# MSBuild timestamp issue with incremental build

Tags: c#, msbuild, t4

I have a C# class library project that references another class library project (EdmResources references Framework). EdmResources only contains a T4 template which is always executed when the project builds, to compile and write out EDMX files for Entity Framework.

The EdmResources project always builds, regardless of whether the Framework assembly is up-to-date or needed to be built as well - this is slowing down our build process a lot. What I want is for EdmResources to only build when the Framework assembly required re-compiling.

I tried outputting the last write time of the Framework assembly as the output of EdmResources.tt, then only do the EDMX generation if the last write time on the assembly is greater than the timestamp recorded in the output file of the template.

This doesn't work though because MSBuild always updates the last write time of the Framework assembly, even if there were no changes and the code was not re-compiled.

Basically, is there a way to generate a signal file from MSBuild during the build of the Framework project that reflects the real build timestamp? IE, it only gets updated when some code is actually re-compiled. That file can then be used instead of the last write time on the Framework assembly.

Thanks!

Comment: this is a fair question however I would always favour rebuilding everything on a build server. have you tried investigating why the build process takes so long for that one project?

Comment: I'm not familiar with T4/Edmx/Entity but had a similar problem once (always generating a resource which led to projects always being built) and solved it by having an msbuild task with a CodeTaskFactory which does `System.IO.File.SetLastWriteTime( DestFile, System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime( SourceFile ) );`. Maybe something like that is useful for you, i.e. forcing the timestamp of a file to something you know is 'old' enough?

Comment: We always rebuild everything on the build server - the problem is when a developer is writing tests and just wants their test project to recompile. Sometimes VS gets it right and just recompiles the test project, but sometimes it goes over all references first. This triggers the resources project to always build, even when the other references are up to date, this is what needs optimizing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good solution. I put this code into my Framework project file at the top:

```
<PropertyGroup>
   <TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
        $(TargetsTriggeredByCompilation);
        AfterCompilation
    </TargetsTriggeredByCompilation>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then added the AfterCompilation target at the bottom of the file:

```
<!-- This target will be called by CoreCompile only when it runs -->
<Target Name="AfterCompilation" >
    <!-- Output Timestamp File -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <SignalFile Include="$(OutDir)MyCompany.Framework.timestamp" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <PropertyGroup>
      <Ticks>$([System.DateTime]::Now.Ticks)</Ticks>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <WriteLinesToFile File="@(SignalFile)" Lines="$(Ticks)" Overwrite="true" />
</Target>
```

So this means that the timestamp file will only be generated when the code compiles, if the CoreCompile target is never called then the timestamp file is not updated. I can then look at this timestamp file from my T4 template and correctly determine if I need to rebuild my EDMX files as well.